# Unable to import settings into a file in a subfolder of the package

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a directory tree that looks like this:

```
lib -
    |
 __init__.py
    |
 settings.py
    |
  helpers-
         |
      space_help.py
         |
      __init__.py
```

I need to import something from `settings.py` into `space_help.py`, however, when I try to import it and run it (*using python 2.7*) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dre234.py", line 10, in <module>
    from lib.settings import CLONE
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\bin\python\dre234\lib\settings.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lib.algorithms.step_up import *
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\bin\python\dre234\lib\algorithms\space_help.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lib.settings import random_salt_generator
ImportError: No module named settings
```

Why am I unable to import this into the file?

Comment: please explicit what version of python you are using, python3 changes lot of import stuff.

Comment: @Arount look at the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to import something with python, it first checks the directory of the current module, then checks the system path. If you want to import something from a folder above your current directory, you'll need to add it to the system path. Like this:

```
import os
import sys

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
sys.path.append(file_path)

from settings import CLONE, random_salt_generator
from algorithms.step_up import *
```